# Putting Bot Framework bot on Github

Tags: git, github, botframework

I recently created my first Microsoft Bot Framework bot and wanted to put it up on my public github so a few friends could add to it. What is the recommended way to do this? I see that they have Continuous deployment setup from github, so I'd imagine there is a recommended way to do this.

I tried downloading the source code and was going to create a repo directly from that, but I noticed that "publish.cmd" in the root of the downloaded code has a token in it, so I can't commit that file to the repo. Is there a certain segment of the downloaded source code that needs to be published?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the `publish.cmd` file in your `.gitignore` file. If you want to be the only responsible person for publishing and deploying the bot then I don't see any problem with proceeding this route.

I don't work with C# Bots as often as I do with Node.js bots, but if you're doing continuous integration you should be rebuilding your solution locally. I don't think you'll need to run the `publish.cmd` or the `build.cmd` (which references the `publish.cmd`).

Comment: Thanks that makes me feel a lot more confident about it! Ideally I'd publish only the relevant files and ignore all the rest (which seems like build and publish but I suspect a few more of the files/folders in the default download are also unnecessary for CI)